# update cart using ajax

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to update the cart item  using ajax with a module.I override a controller and product add to cart from view page works fine.can annyone tell me that how to update the cart item without reloading of page.

my config.xml is

```
 <config>
    <modules>
        <Module_Ajax>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Module_Ajax>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <ajax>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Module_Ajax</module>
                    <frontName>ajax</frontName>
                </args>
            </ajax>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <ajax>
                    <file>ajax.xml</file>
                </ajax>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>   
    <global>
        <resources>
            <ajax_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Module_Ajax</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </ajax_setup>
            <ajax_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </ajax_write>
            <ajax_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </ajax_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <global>
        <rewrite>
            <ajax_cart> <!--This can be any unique id -->
                <from><![CDATA[#^/checkout/cart/#]]></from>
                <to>/ajax/index/</to>
            </ajax_cart>
        </rewrite>
    </global>
</config>
```

This is CartController which I overridded and I want to update cart item
my controller file is

```
    <?php
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';
class Module_Ajax_IndexController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController {
    public function addAction()
    {
        $cart   = $this->_getCart();
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        if($params['isAjax'] == 1){
            $response = array();
            try {
                if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                    $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                    array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode())
                    );
                    $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
                }

                $product = $this->_initProduct();
                $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');

                /**
                 * Check product availability
                 */
                if (!$product) {
                    $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
                    $response['message'] = $this->__('Unable to find Product ID');
                }

                $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
                if (!empty($related)) {
                    $cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
                }

                $cart->save();

                $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);

                /**
                 * @todo remove wishlist observer processAddToCart
                 */
                Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
                array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
                );

                if (!$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()){
                    $message = $this->__('%s was added to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()));
                    $response['status'] = 'SUCCESS';
                    $response['message'] = $message;
                    //New Code Here
                    $this->loadLayout();
                    $toplink = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('top.links')->toHtml();
                    $sidebar_block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('cart_sidebar');
                    Mage::register('referrer_url', $this->_getRefererUrl());
                    $sidebar = $sidebar_block->toHtml();
                    $response['toplink'] = $toplink;
                    $response['sidebar'] = $sidebar;
                }
            } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                $msg = "";
                if ($this->_getSession()->getUseNotice(true)) {
                    $msg = $e->getMessage();
                } else {
                    $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
                    foreach ($messages as $message) {
                        $msg .= $message.'<br/>';
                    }
                }

                $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
                $response['message'] = $msg;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
                $response['message'] = $this->__('Cannot add the item to shopping cart.');
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
            return;
        }else{
            return parent::addAction();
        }
    }

    public function optionsAction(){
        $productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_id');
        // Prepare helper and params
        $viewHelper = Mage::helper('catalog/product_view');

        $params = new Varien_Object();
        $params->setCategoryId(false);
        $params->setSpecifyOptions(false);

        // Render page
        try {
            $viewHelper->prepareAndRender($productId, $this, $params);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if ($e->getCode() == $viewHelper->ERR_NO_PRODUCT_LOADED) {
                if (isset($_GET['store'])  && !$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
                    $this->_redirect('');
                } elseif (!$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
                    $this->_forward('noRoute');
                }
            } else {
                Mage::logException($e);
                $this->_forward('noRoute');
            }
        }
    }

    protected function _getWishlist($wishlistId = null)
    {
        $wishlist = Mage::registry('wishlist');
        if ($wishlist) {
            return $wishlist;
        }
        try {
            if (!$wishlistId) {
                $wishlistId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('wishlist_id');
            }
            $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
            $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist');

            if ($wishlistId) {
                $wishlist->load($wishlistId);
            } else {
                $wishlist->loadByCustomer($customerId, true);
            }
            if (!$wishlist->getId() || $wishlist->getCustomerId() != $customerId) {
                $wishlist = null;
                Mage::throwException(
                    Mage::helper('wishlist')->__("Requested wishlist doesn't exist")
                );
            }

            Mage::register('wishlist', $wishlist);
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('wishlist/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('wishlist/session')->addException($e,
            Mage::helper('wishlist')->__('Cannot create wishlist.')
            );
            return false;
        }

        return $wishlist;
    }
    public function addwishAction()
    {

        $response = array();
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('wishlist/general/active')) {
            $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
            $response['message'] = $this->__('Wishlist Has Been Disabled By Admin');
        }
        if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
            $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
            $response['message'] = $this->__('Please Login First');
        }

        if(empty($response)){
            $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
            $wishlist = $this->_getWishlist();
            if (!$wishlist) {
                $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
                $response['message'] = $this->__('Unable to Create Wishlist');
            }else{

                $productId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('product');
                if (!$productId) {
                    $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
                    $response['message'] = $this->__('Product Not Found');
                }else{

                    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
                    if (!$product->getId() || !$product->isVisibleInCatalog()) {
                        $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
                        $response['message'] = $this->__('Cannot specify product.');
                    }else{

                        try {
                            $requestParams = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
                            if ($session->getBeforeWishlistRequest()) {
                                $requestParams = $session->getBeforeWishlistRequest();
                                $session->unsBeforeWishlistRequest();
                            }
                            $buyRequest = new Varien_Object($requestParams);

                            $result = $wishlist->addNewItem($product, $buyRequest);
                            if (is_string($result)) {
                                Mage::throwException($result);
                            }
                            $wishlist->save();

                            Mage::dispatchEvent(
                                'wishlist_add_product',
                            array(
                                'wishlist'  => $wishlist,
                                'product'   => $product,
                                'item'      => $result
                            )
                            );


                            $referer = $session->getBeforeWishlistUrl();
                            if ($referer) {
                                $session->setBeforeWishlistUrl(null);
                            } else {
                                $referer = $this->_getRefererUrl();
                            }
                            $session->setAddActionReferer($referer);

                            Mage::helper('wishlist')->calculate();

                            $message = $this->__('%1$s has been added to your wishlist.',
                            $product->getName(), Mage::helper('core')->escapeUrl($referer));

                            $response['status'] = 'SUCCESS';
                            $response['message'] = $message;

                            Mage::unregister('wishlist');

                            $this->loadLayout();
                            $toplink = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('top.links')->toHtml();
                            $sidebar_block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('wishlist_sidebar');
                            $sidebar = $sidebar_block->toHtml();
                            $response['toplink'] = $toplink;
                            $response['sidebar'] = $sidebar;
                        }
                        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                            $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
                            $response['message'] = $this->__('An error occurred while adding item to wishlist: %s', $e->getMessage());
                        }
                        catch (Exception $e) {
                            mage::log($e->getMessage());
                            $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
                            $response['message'] = $this->__('An error occurred while adding item to wishlist.');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
        return;
    }
    public function compareAction(){
        $response = array();

        $productId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('product');

        if ($productId && (Mage::getSingleton('log/visitor')->getId() || Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())) {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->load($productId);

            if ($product->getId()/* && !$product->isSuper()*/) {
                Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_compare_list')->addProduct($product);
                $response['status'] = 'SUCCESS';
                $response['message'] = $this->__('The product %s has been added to comparison list.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()));
                Mage::register('referrer_url', $this->_getRefererUrl());
                Mage::helper('catalog/product_compare')->calculate();
                Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_compare_add_product', array('product'=>$product));
                $this->loadLayout();
                $sidebar_block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.compare.sidebar');
                $sidebar_block->setTemplate('ajaxwishlist/catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml');
                $sidebar = $sidebar_block->toHtml();
                $response['sidebar'] = $sidebar;
            }
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you face any error in above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For calling Ajax you have to first call the checkout cart block

```
 $cartHtml =  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart')->setTemplate('checkout/cart.phtml')->toHtml();
```

After that you have to send response to your cart.phtml file where your Ajax code is written.

```
$response['cart_html'] = $cartHtml;
$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
```